# #defines as nameless enum in Cython (nested in struct)

Tags: c, macros, struct, enums, cython

I have the following code from a C header:

```
typedef struct
{     /* struct description */
      int type;               /* variable purpose: */
#define OPTION_A          1  /* option A */
#define OPTION_B          2  /* option B */
#define OPTION_C          3  /* option C */
} struct_name;
```

As Cython, in a pxd file, I think I should write this as (cf. [reference](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#referencing-c-header-files)):

```
ctypedef struct struct_name: # struct description
    cdef enum purpose:
        OPTION_A = 1 # option A
        OPTION_B = 2 # option B
        OPTION_C = 3 # option C
    enum purpose type # variable purpose
```

However, in C, I think I can also write the same code using a nameless `enum` as

```
typedef struct
{     /* struct description */
      enum {
        OPTION_A          1  /* option A */
        OPTION_B          2  /* option B */
        OPTION_C          3  /* option C */
      } type;               /* variable purpose: */
} struct_name;
```

My question is whether I can also use this type of pattern in Cython, so that I can avoid introducing the named `enum` `purpose`.